# Xcode load data in new view dependant on button

Tags: ios, xcode, button, view

I have one view with a considerable amount of buttons in it all leading to a new view. I would like to display different data in the new view dependant on what button was pressed to enter it.

A point in the right direction would be awesome.

Comment: Are you working on iPhone? Can you post some code?

Comment: Yep iOS5 and storyboards

Comment: Do all buttons load the same new view? Are you using view controllers? How do you differentiate between that various buttons (with their tag, label)?

Comment: Are buttons created programmaticaly or in IB?

Comment: yeah all buttons lead to the same view (Its a really simple view just displaying some info on what button was pressed so seems silly to have like 30 views).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connect your buttons to the new view controller using segues.  Then you can implement the method `prepareForSegue:sender:` in the view controller containing your buttons.  In that method you can set properties on your new view with whatever data is needed to customize your new view.  You'll need to determine which button was clicked.  One way of doing that would be to set the `tag` property of each button to a different value (either in IB or in your code).

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // sender is the button that was clicked
    // you could set the tag property of the UIButtons when they are created
    // and inspect that property here to determine which was clicked

    // vc will be the view controller you are segueing to
    YourViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];

    // set properies of youe next view controller with data needed by new view
    switch (sender.tag) {
        case 0:   // first button
            vc.myProperty = someData;
            break;
        case 1:   // second button
            vc.myProperty = someOtherData;
            break;

        etc...
    }

}
```

Comment: Right, I'll give this a shot. Looks exactly what I need...will let post how I get on

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to link your buttons to a function like

```
- (IBAction) buttonClicked: (UIButton*) sender;
```

And then depending on what button has been clicked (you can set their tag attributes to differentiate them and them get the `sender.tag` value to know what button has been click), you just call the corresponding function in your new view to update its data.